# Make vim more verbose (make keystrokes visible)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

So I'm trying to demo vim, but no one can see the keys i'm pressing. Is there a way to have it show the last string of commands?
Like...this being displayed in the corner.

```
<esc>v:28yyGpi
```

some text

```
<esc><ctrl><shift>c10jllI
```

more text...
 ect...

If worse comes to worse I could probably make something, But I had hoped there was some built in function.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no such built-in functions. but you can turn to other tools, to show the keystrokes on screen. They are available on win/mac/linux. you can set many options.

Comment: [screenkey.ahk](https://github.com/mihaifm/screenkey.ahk), I made it specifically for this purpose :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Vim itself for that, use an external program like [KeyCastr](https://github.com/sdeken/keycastr) on Mac OS X, [QiPress](http://aalapshah.in/qipress/) on Windows or [key-mon](https://code.google.com/p/key-mon/) on Linux. There are many others so make sure you review them all before choosing one of the above.